# pcl::ConvexHull inconsistent getArea and getVolume values

Tags: pcl, qhull

If I acquire, segment and at the end process via pcl::ConvexHull a relatively flat face of an object without setting it as 2D or 3D the convexhull sometimes classifies it as 2D, sometimes as 3D (and that is quite normal because it is flat with some noise and some small part of a second side which is not completely filtered out)

but the results I get with getArea() and getVolume() are totally inconsistent and not justified by the slight difference there is between the subsequent acquisitions I obtain from my Intel realsense.

Without moving the object I am getting these results (I quote just two examples):
(the object is a box which has a main visible side of 9cm x 20cm -> 0.018 m2 )

(1)

------ output inherent in qhull used by PCL:

Convex hull of 80663 points in 2-d:

Number of vertices: 22
Number of facets: 22

Statistics for:  | qhull FA

Number of points processed: 22
Number of hyperplanes created: 42
Number of distance tests for qhull: 532571
CPU seconds to compute hull (after input): 0.006

Total facet area:   0.57170199

Total volume:       0.017460552

----- output from my PCL based application:

Convex cluster hull 0 area (getArea()): 0.0174606

Convex cluster hull 0 vol. (getVolume()): 0

Convex unflatness (1/flatness) : 0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjTkY.png)

(2)

------ output inherent in qhull used by PCL:

Convex hull of 80571 points in 3-d:

Number of vertices: 86
Number of facets: 151
Number of non-simplicial facets: 11

Statistics for:  | qhull FA

Number of points processed: 109
Number of hyperplanes created: 487
Number of distance tests for qhull: 854976
Number of distance tests for merging: 2495
Number of distance tests for checking: 1850
Number of merged facets: 26
CPU seconds to compute hull (after input): 0.008

Approximate facet area:   0.042347971

Approximate volume:       0.00026576258

----- output from my PCL based application:

Convex cluster hull 0 area (getArea()): 0.042348

Convex cluster hull 0 vol.(getVolume()): 0.000265763

Convex unflatness (1/flatness) : 0.200883

(as you can see the clouds are just slightly different)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcAQh.png)

The facet area and facet volume I get in the two cases are totally inconsistent and PCL tries to compensate with it in the first case by loading the volume as if it was an area and by setting the volume to zero (which from my point of view makes the general result even worse).

I don't know what I am missing here but I would expect more similar values of at least the area value, as the surface is basically the same with minimum differences between the two acquisitions. I understand that if the surface of the cloud is classified as 2D or 3D different algorithms are triggered but the value of the convex hull of a flat surface should not be so different. Say it multiplied roughly by 2 considering a 3D convex hull would have 2++ main sides.

I will try to plot now also the polygons of the convex hull to better understand what is going on

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey I might have found an answer to my question but please confirm if I am right or not.
I had wrongly noted down the effective area of the surface which is 0.018 m^2.
Well in that case that makes sense with the given 2D surface of 0.0174606 and it also makes quite sense with the 3D given surface of 0.042348 because it can be considered like a 3D wrapping of the surface (so roughly > 0.017*2). STILL the doubt holds for the fact that qhull in the 2d case gives

Total facet area: 0.57170199

Total volume: 0.017460552

but that is probably explained by qhull giving a weird output where the area is  in fact a curvilinear border length and the volume is in fact an area? Is it so??

Thanks